# How queryBy without html tags with React testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I use React testing library for my unit test.

I want to test this of my React component:

```
return (
    <div>
      <p data-testid="my-string">
        {string}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
```

After I query `queryByTestId`  the component I receive something like:

```
 <p class="css-1317scs-myString" data-testid="my-string">&lt;iframe src="src="https://my-site.com?id=6533cf73&autoplay=false" allowfullscreen seamless frameborder="0" allow="encrypted-media"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;</p>
```

So with all the html tags etc.

```
 expect(queryByTestId('my-string')).toBe(
      '<iframe src="https://my-site.com?id=6533cf73&autoplay=false" allowfullscreen seamless frameborder="0" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>'
    );
```

I just want to test if `<iframe src="https://my-site.com?id=6533cf73&autoplay=false" allowfullscreen seamless frameborder="0" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>` is exactly defined like this.

How do I get rid of all those html tags. Or do I have to use another approach?

Comment: What does the react component you are testing look like? Could you post the part of the markup you are testing?

Comment: @g0rb I added it to my question. Thanks

Comment: `expect('queryByTestId('my-string')?.innerHTML').toBe('<iframe src="https://my-site.com?id=6533cf73&autoplay=false" allowfullscreen seamless frameborder="0" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>');` maybe?

Comment: @g0rb thanks. It's still expect `&lt;iframe src=\"https://`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the content of all the elements inside of the queried element, you should use `textContent` on the queried element.

```
expect(queryByTestId('my-string').textContent)
    .toBe('&lt;iframe src="src="https://my-site.com?id=6533cf73&autoplay=false" allowfullscreen seamless frameborder="0" allow="encrypted-media"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;');
```

Yes, the rendered string in your component will swap out the `<` angle bracket character for `&lt;`. React encodes the `<` and `>` characters automatically to prevent [XSS attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/).

If you **really** want the brackets rendered, you can use React's [dangerouslySetInnerHtml attribute](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml). You can use it like so:

```
<p data-testid="my-string" 
   dangerouslySetInnerHTML={string}
></p>
```

After applying the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute, you should see the actual `<` brackets rendered in your app and in your test.